# git bash on windows not picking up maven options and giving out of memory error

Tags: git, maven, git-bash

I am getting out of space error so i increased size in mvn.bat at MAVEN_HOME/bin with

```
set  MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx756m -XX:MaxPermSize=756M
```

Running from windows cmd, it picks up the maven options and runs fine. When i run this from git bash these options are not picked up and i am getting out of memory error. I tried closing and restarting git bash shell and confirmed both are running maven from same maven home directory.

I want to use git bash instead of cmd because my project is git based and i prefer unix commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding maven options to .bashrc fixed it:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx756m -XX:MaxPermSize=756M"
```